# How to use req.responseText, in Ajax to return only the content inside a div of a page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using XMLHttp request in Ajax, but I have a problem. I want that to use this `document.getElementById('partid').innerHTML=request.responseText`
in a way that return only the content inside the `div`called`'cars'` of the page export.php. But when I use it like above it return all the content of the page export.php. Is there any way to make this line of code to return only the content inside a div?
 I am trying to use it like:

`document.getElementById('partid').innerHTML=request.responseText.getElementById('cars').`
, but it does not function.

Please,help me. I have spend hours searching but i have not find anything about this..Please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`request.responseText` is just text perform any DOM operations on it. You can parse it with jQuery though and find the required content.

```
$('#partid').html($(request.responseText).find('#cars').html());
```

http://api.jquery.com/find/
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: where to write this? Instead of document.getElementById('partid').innerHTML=request.responseText ?

Comment: but div partid is not in the same file with cars div

Comment: or should I write document.getElementById('partid').innerHTML=$('#partid').html($(request.responseText).find('#cars').html());

Answer (score 0):

When `responseText` comes back, it is -- as the name suggests -- text.

Before you can access it as HTML, you have to turn it INTO HTML.

This is typed off the cuff, but it would be something like:

```
var tempdiv = document.createElement("div");
tmpdiv.innerHTML = request.responseText;
var wantedDiv = tmpDiv.querySelector('[id="cars"]');
// Might want to empty out 'partid' first
document.getElementById('partid').appendChild(wantedDiv);
```